# Azure AAD - AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

I am pulling my hair out with this one.

I have a .Net Core 2.1 application on the back-end with Angular 7 in the front.

I've already done all the difficult work of getting integration with Azure Active Directory up and working, and it is properly connecting me to AAD, asking for credentials, then at the last stage I get:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application

I am testing this locally for rapid development and I have my callback set to:

https://localhost:5001/azureauth/auth

This is directly in the Azure Portal:

[image]

This controller method currently does nothing but hit a break point, which if I hit it manually in the browser properly breaks in the controller method.

Azure won't call me back on it after a successful AD login.

What am I missing?

**Edit** I noticed that the query string when connecting to AAD has the following in the "redirect" portion, which does not match what I have in Azure as it does not have the path it's just localhost:5001 ... does this matter?

[image: Redirect Path]

**OpenID Settings**

[image: OpenID Settings]

/azureauth/auth is my controller and my method.

[image: Error]

Comment: check the localstorage / sessionstorage of your browser. It contains useful information about what is the problem. In case you still face problems, please update the question with details from it.

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio The localstorage/sessionstorage for login.microsoftonline.com are both blank.  I've updated my question to include a redirectURL that seems wrong?

Comment: Is there something wrong with my *outbound* request here?

Comment: since they are controlled by azure ad, I can't tell you what is wrong. To me, looks the application inside Azure AD is configured to use a different url than https://localhost:5001/azureauth/auth

Comment: Can you post the application settings in here?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Done.

Comment: no, this part https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/09/SecureLogicApps30.png then go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/websdk/images/troubleshooting/auth/configuringreplyurlinazure.png

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio I am on the new portal so I don't have those exact settings but that "Reply URL" should be the same as my "Redirect URI" as shown above, no?

Comment: yes, they should be the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Application's list of Redirect URIs must contain the `PostLogoutRedirectUri` value, exactly as written in OpenIdSettings.

In this case, go to AAD Portal and add a Redirect URI for `http://localhost:5001`

Ideally, you should update the OpenIdSettings and Application Registration to use https instead of http.

Comment: I resolved this prior to seeing this, but you are correct, changing it to simply `https://localhost:5001` is properly letting me through via AAD.